# Find bad dynamic SQL statements containing syntax errors in Oracle

Tags: oracle, logging, dynamic-sql

I was wondering if there is a way to find dynamic SQL statements whose execution broke during runtime in case there was no proper exception handling in the PL/SQL program unit that called the dynanic SQL.

```
procedure will_crash is
begin
   -- 1000 dynamic sql statements here ..

   execute immediate 'updaXte dual set X = ''Z'' ' ;

   -- ... and 1000 more dynamic sql statements here ..
   commit;
end;  --> NO proper exception handling for logging the last sql statement
```

In case a nighttime scheduled program unit contains hundreds of dynamic sql statements, I'd like to find out which one broke without debugging. Does Oracle log anything in its system views?

Comment: Define "broke".  Most likely, no.  If we're talking about simple syntax errors, that isn't going to be logged.  If the "nighttime scheduled program unit" is scheduled via the database and the error propagates all the way up to the caller, the error stack would get logged (where depends on what scheduling mechanism you're using).  That stack trace would include a line number which may help you assuming that you really have thousands of lines of code rather than a loop that is building thousands of distinct SQL statements.

Comment: Maybe this helps?  https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2

Comment: I use my package with execute_immediate procedure - wrapper around dbms_sql/execute immediate. It has buildin logging of sql text before execution, execution time, sql%rowcount and explain_plan after execution. In case of error it logs error stack, code  and etc.

Comment: That's a good approach, but my question was specificly addressed to scenarios with no proper exception handling. I was curious about the existence of an internal LOG in Oracle able to trace such bad SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

In you're example there's no need at all to use dynamic SQL, so the easiest solution is to rewrite it as

```
procedure will_crash is
begin
   -- 1000 dynamic sql statements here ..

   updaXte dual set X = ''Z''; -- Error at compile time!!

   -- ... and 1000 more dynamic sql statements here ..
   commit;
end;  --> NO proper exception handling for logging the last sql statement
```

If the real procedure uses dynamic SQL because the SQL statements are saved elsewhere (variables or SQL table), and we're talking only about syntax error, you can achieve your objective before executing statements using DBMS_SQL package. 
Here's an example:

```
DECLARE

    lc_good   VARCHAR2(200) := 'SELECT 1 FROM dual';
    lc_bad    VARCHAR2(200) := 'SEL1ECT a FROM dual';
    lc_cursor NUMBER;

BEGIN

    lc_cursor := SYS.DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

    BEGIN
        SYS.DBMS_SQL.PARSE(lc_cursor, lc_good, DBMS_SQL.V7);
        dbms_output.put_line('Statement 1 is GOOD');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Statement 1 is BAD: ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

    BEGIN
        SYS.DBMS_SQL.PARSE(lc_cursor, lc_bad, DBMS_SQL.V7);
        dbms_output.put_line('Statement 2 is GOOD');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Statement 2 is BAD: ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

    SYS.DBMS_SQL.close_cursor(lc_cursor);

END;
```

The function output is the following:

```
Statement 1 is GOOD
Statement 2 is BAD: ORA-00900: ...
```

Note that the code only parses the SQL statements, it don't executes them.